# How to compare the values in a timestamp column with the user input using MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table which contains a timestamp column.

I need to compare the values in timestamp column with user input and extract the whole row from the table.

timestamp column

---

```
29-10-14 07:20:01.00000

26-10-14 07:20:01.00000

27-10-14 07:20:01.00000

28-10-14 10:00:00.00000
```

I tried the below line in the Where clause

```
to_char(timestampcol,'DD-MON-YY HH12:MI:SS')= to_char(sysdate,'DD-MON-YY 10:00:00')
```

but dint succeed.
please help.

Thanks in advance,

Shreyas Athreya S

Comment: maybe you can use `FROM_UNIXTIME('some_date', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')` in query

Comment: can you be more specific with an example?

Comment: if user input date has format `Y-m-d H:i:s` you can write next query `SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME('timestampcol', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') = 'user_date'` and in format is another you have to change `'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s'`

Comment: actually the user only provides the time.. date should match the system date..

Comment: are you use some other programming language or only SQL

Comment: i'm using only SQL and executing it in unix platform

Comment: mb `SELECT * FROM table WHERE timestampcol = DATE_FORMAT(CONCAT_WS(' ', CURDATE(), '11:00:11'), '%d-%m-%y %H:%i:%s')`  where '11:00:11' user input time

Comment: it dint work... it gave an error saying sql query not ended properly..

Comment: can you show example of query ?